# Error while passing strings in functions in Haskell

Tags: list, function, haskell, char

So I tried the following code in haskell where I try to detect if the user has entered a "no" or "No" in the string. Also I tried replacing [[Char]] with Strings but it gives compilation errors.

```
  wantGifts :: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
  wantGifts st = [if (x == "No" || x== "no") then "No gifts given" else "But why" | x <-  st, x == head st]
```

The above code compiles but when I pass a string to it, it returns an error message:

```
*Main> wantGifts "no I dont"

<interactive>:8:11:
    Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’
    Expected type: [[Char]]
      Actual type: [Char]
    In the first argument of ‘wantGifts’, namely ‘"no I dont"’
    In the expression: wantGifts "no I dont"
    In an equation for ‘it’: it = wantGifts "no I dont"
```

Comment: The error says that the function expects a list of strings (list-of-lists-of-chars), but you do not pass one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closely at the type of `wantGifts`, it requires a List of List of Chars. But `"no I dont"` is of type `String` which is just `[Char]`. With your current construction, you have to use:

```
wantGifts ["no I dont"]
```

There are several ways to improve this, best is to use [`Text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.1/docs/Data-Text.html).

```
import Data.Text (Text)
import qualified Data.Text as T
wantGifts :: Text -> Text 
wantGifts txt = if (T.isInfixOf "no" . T.toLower) txt then "No gifts given" else "But why"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have defined `wantGifts` as taking a list of strings. `[[Char]]` is equivalent to `[String]`. In the REPL, you are passing it a single string.

If you instead did this, it would compile:

```hs
wantGifts ["no I dont"]
```

However, I have a hunch this isn't what you want.

If you were trying to detect whether the word `"no"` was anywhere in the string, you could use the `words` function:

```hs
containsNo :: String -> Bool
containsNo = any (\w -> w == "no" || w == "No") . words
```

Comment: Thanks, I would be thankful if you could explain that \w and any part.

Comment: That is lambda syntax for anonymous functions. [Here is a good explanation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Anonymous_function).

Comment: @Sudhanshu [LearnYouAHaskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/higher-order-functions) is also an excellent resource to learn from.

Comment: @jkeuhlen Its my primary resource for learning haskell and it surely is a good one!